# Emacs not listing semilight fonts?

Tags: fonts, emacs

I wanted to use a `semilight` font. But, for some reason, emacs is not listing `semilight` fonts. Am I missing anything?

In my `init.el`, I have the following:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Cascadia Code" :weight 'semilight)
```

However, when running `describe-char` on any character, I get that it's using `-SAJA-Cascadia Code-light-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`, which turns out to be from *CascadiaCode-Regular.otf*.

I tried to find the main reason why it was happening:

- When I run `describe-font`, I can't seem to find any of the `semilight` fonts in my system (i.e. `weight=55`). The only font that shows up as `semilight` is a font whose weight is 75.
- Running `x-select-font` lists the `semilight` fonts.

I'm not really sure what is happening here. Shouldn't emacs show these fonts whose `weight=55`? If so, any thought on why that isn't happening?

---

Environment:

- GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.29, cairo version
  1.17.4) of 2021-04-27
- Fedora 34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the font files is a bit too heavy-handed, and unmaintainable, as Cascadia is fairly new, and is released often.

It is possible to substitute `semilight` weight value (55) to `book` (75) during cache rebuild, which makes Emacs happily display the Cascadia SemiLight variants when `'semi-light` is assigned as the `:weight` property of a face. Unfortunately, this trick can be pulled only with a cached font description. Fontconfig is esoteric.

Place this config file into a location that is scanned by `fc-cache`: per-user, or into `/etc/fonts/conf.d` for all users (usually; `fc-conflist` will tell which directories it's looking into; file `50-user.conf` normally includes `.conf` files from home directories). The files that affect cache scan customarily prefixed with a number in the range 80 to 89. I have this file as `/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-cascadia-semilight.conf`; you may have your own preferences.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

  <description>Adjust weight of Cascadia fonts for Emacs</description>

  <match target="scan">
    <test target="font" name="family" ignore-blanks="true">
      <string>Cascadia Mono</string>
    </test>
    <test target="font" name="weight">
      <const>semilight</const>
    </test>
    <edit name="weight">
      <const>book</const>
    </edit>
  </match>

  <!-- Repeat the same match stanza for the other three fonts,
       Cascadia Mono PL, Cascadia Code and Cascadia Code PL. -->

</fontconfig>
```

Or get it [lock, stock and barrel from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/kkm000/2373722b012ec6fedc3f6d1729c6cc20).

Comment: I don't think fontconfig is esoteric here. It's really crucial to use `target=scan` here, but the reason is that emacs doesn't really use fontconfig in the usual way, see my explanation in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=67810#47 and bug reports  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25147 and https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17792.

Comment: @real-or-random: I don't know which are _you_ in the thread where two posters exchange 47 messages. In either case, I can't help keeping my opinion unchanged: if a concept requires 47 messages back and forth to explain, it's probably esoteric. But this is just an opinion. Some prefer oatmeal, some like it hot... :)

Comment: Hehe, agreed. The point I tried to make is that emacs is the esoteric piece here and not fontconfig. But, this is probably not a black and white thing anyway. The entire story is certainly esoteric. :)  (I'm Tim Ruffing by the way.)

Comment: “emacs is the esoteric piece here” — oh yeah, 100%! It was born before even X, and then hacked to <s>a Frankenstein monster</s> support all the ways fonts were supported (and semisupported, and attempted to support) since then. X font handling is an architectural mess.

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little bit through what `fontconfig` was doing with the OTF files, and how Emacs was parsing the font weights given by `fontconfig`, I found the real culprit.

It probably is a bug in Emacs. That's because by comparing [`fontconfig` spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) with [how Emacs understands font-weights](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/src/font.c), there are a few differences. Notably, one of them involves the `semilight` font-weight.

One way around it is to use `fontforge`, and change the OTF font-weight to something Emacs understands. So, for example:

1. change the OTF font-weight of, say, *Cascadia Code SemiLight.otf* from 350 (`fontconfig`'s semilight) to 380 (`fontconfig`'s book)
2. `fontconfig` will convert that value according to [their table](https://github.com/freedesktop/fontconfig/blob/2.13.93/src/fcweight.c) to `FC_WEIGHT_BOOK` (75)
3. Emacs will show that as semilight